# Looking For Ideas of Vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm looking to create a calculated column based value from another column with few conditions.

1. Evaluate only when ['EVENT'] is 'Injecting'
2. Find the first ['EVENT_TIME'] where the ['EVENT'] is 'Flowing'
3. group result based on unique id ['CMPL_RC_UID']

here's my code

```
def next_event(row,table):
    if row['EVENT'] == 'Injecting':
        return table[(table['EVENT'] == 'Flowing') & (table['EVENT_TIME'] > 
           row['EVENT_TIME'])].groupby('CMPL_RC_UID')['EVENT_TIME'].min().values[0]
    else:
        pass

ev_table.apply(lambda row: next_event(row, ev_table), axis=1)
```

I'm currently using .apply and it gives me result that I'm looking for but my df have a lot of data and it's taking a really long time to process. So I'm wondering if there's a way to vectorize the code .

| CMPL_RC_UID | EVENT | EVENT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10074 | Flowing | 1/20/2011 |
| 10074 | Injecting | 12/22/2010 |
| 10074 | Flowing | 1/6/2010 |
| 10074 | Injecting | 12/10/2009 |

Comment: Just to clarify, if the criteria is not met, the value should be blank?  Could you also please provide the table you're using.  Lastly, I would tab the if and else statements once for readability.

Comment: that's correct the new column is created based on the EVENTS column and when EVENTS are not 'Injecting' the new column should be blank

Comment: Added sample table code for reference